How to translate only a part of my page to a specific language?
In Django I can use activate() (and deactivate()) to temporarily switch translations to be done in a different language. And similarly, in templates, I can use the {% language %} template tag.
This allows me to translate into a general language for the full page, but render a specific part of it in another language.
Is it possible to do something similar with i18next, rendering some components in another language?
Update:
Thanks to comment from @Avi, I'm getting a little closer with the answers here. But this only allows me to specify the language for a single string. What I would like to do is set the language for a component and all of its sub components. Is that possible?

Does this answer your question? How can I use two translations on the same react app with i18next?

Thanks! It's in the right direction, but not quite yet there. I've updated the question to be more specific about what I want to achieve.

You can use a similar approach to what is mentioned in the link I suggested. Instead of applying the lng option to a specific translation, you can apply it to the t function when you call the useTranslation hook.
const { t } = useTranslation('context', { lng: 'de' });
That way, all the translations that use the t function in the file will use the language you specified (German in this example). I don't think the component decedents can just inherit this by default but you can always pass the t function as a prop to other components so you know they all use the same t function you defined in the parent component
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('context', { lng: 'de' });

  return (
    <AnotherComponent t={t} />
  )
}

const AnotherComponent  = ({ t }) => {
  const myTranslation = t('settings');

  return <p>{myTranslation }</p>
}

